# huff model in gis

Tags: python, gis, modeling, raster

how would be the simplest version of the Huff model for territorial and economic analysis? sig using algorithms that I recommend or free libraries for working with files both vector and raster OGR

Comment: I have a script for a euclidian distance Huff model I would be happy to clean up and share.  Are you needing euclidian distance or network distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options within ArcGIS environment that might be of some help:

1. Python script [here](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15999)
2. SANET tool for network analysis [here](http://sanet.csis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Also linked to/asked on GIS.SE https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6219/open-source-gis-implementation-of-the-huff-model

Script for R - http://www.reymann.eu/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/GravitationsgesetzHuff.R